# How to Update A boolean value in mongo using mongoite in R

Tags: r, mongolite

I am unable to update a bool value in mongo using mongolite. I have a bool value (FALSE) in r and I am trying to update a field in mongo which is currently having value true(mongo bool). But After making update command using mongolite, stored bool value true in mongo changed to string value FALSE(R bool type).

Answer (score 0):

mongolite doesn't automatically update `r` booleans as `mongo` booleans.

this throws an `Error: Invalid JSON object` for me:

`m$update('{"name":"foo", "$set":{"boolean":FALSE}}')`

this inserts `FALSE` as string:

`m$update('{"name":"foo", "$set":{"boolean":"FALSE"}}')`

this inserts false as boolean:

`m$update('{"name":"foo", "$set":{"boolean":false}}')`

if you're making the update query programmatically you can do something like this:

```

```
my_boolean <- FALSE
my_updateQuery <- paste0('{"$set":{"boolean":',tolower(paste0(my_boolean)),'}}')
m$update('{"name":"foo", my_updateQuery)
```

```